# analyze network traffic to and from the process

Tags: networking, tcpdump, nmap

Is there any way on Linux to get detailed  analysis of network traffic to and from a process . Detailed analysis means the data as provided by tcpdump, wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

How about using lsof to get further information on the process?

lsof -c $process

to see what files and network connections that are used by the process.

lsof -i | egrep 'mongod.*LISTEN'

to grep for all connections to the mongod process. From this you can see what port the process is listening on

$ lsof -i | egrep 'mongod.*LISTEN'

mongod    64223 fred    6u  IPv4 0xffffff80298fec20      0t0  TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)

mongod    64223 fred    7u  IPv4 0xffffff8017393500      0t0  TCP *:28017 (LISTEN)

mongod    64224 fred    9u  IPv4 0xffffff8014038500      0t0  TCP *:27018 (LISTEN)

mongod    64224 fred   10u  IPv4 0xffffff801746f880      0t0  TCP *:28018 (LISTEN)

......

......

......

and so then run tcpdump on that port.

HTH!